# How to ignore lazy="false" mapping?

Tags: nhibernate

I have following class:

```
public class PurchaseOrder
{
   ...
   Store Store { get; protected set; }
   User CreatedBy { get; protected set; }
   User ApprovedBy { get; protected set; }
   ...
}
```

User and Store classes are mapped with lazy="false" option.

```
<class name="User" lazy="false">
```

More to say them associated to some other entities that mapped with `lazy="false"` option. **And I am not allowed to change it.** It's not "my" classes, them belongs to other domains.

My problem that every time that I fetch PurchaseOrder it produces additional queries for those classes and their dependencies leading me to SELECT N+1 problem. In 99% of cases I do not need all that information - store id and user id is enough for me.
Tried to use ...

```
session.CreateCreteria<PurchaseOrder>()
   ...
   .SetFetchMode("CreatedBy", FetchMode.Lazy)
   .SetFetchMode("ApprovedBy", FetchMode.Lazy)
   .SetFetchMode("Store", FetchMode.Lazy)
   ...
```

.. but it does not help.

How can I force those associations to be lazy and to ignore `lazy="false"`?

Just to be clear. The information that stored in User and Store classes is useless for my domain. So I do not want it to be fetched at all. Also if I join users and stores in my query it will lead to chain of queries for entities that also mapped as lazy="false" (do not ask why, I can't change it). I aligned to some company's standard and must reference those classes (I do not like it but this is a rule), but I do not want to fetch their data, i want it lazy.

Answer (score 2):

You can't override `lazy="false"`.

What you can do is the exact oposite of what you did: fetch eagerly (`FetchMode.Eager` or `FetchMode.Join`, which are synonyms).

Comment: I do not want to fetch associated users and store at all.

Comment: Then you'll have to talk to the moron that created the mapping. As said, it cannot be overridden. Alternatively, you can use a projection, but you'll lose all forms of change tracking, identity map, etc. Suggested read (for you and your coworker): http://ayende.com/blog/4573/nhibernate-is-lazy-just-live-with-it